# Maxwell's relations and adiabats

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, elasticity, adiabatic

I was trying to understand problem regarding finding the adiabatic modulus given the isothermal young's modulus. I'm still an amateur in thermodynamics.
I just didn't understand the final step where the two adiabats are combined.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set $dS=0$ in the two equations for $dS$:
$$
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
   dS = 0 = \dfrac{m c_F}{T} + \left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial T}\right)_F dF \\ 
   dS = 0 = \dfrac{m c_L}{T} - \left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_L dL  
\end{array}
\right\}
\Rightarrow
\begin{array}{l}
   dF = -\dfrac{m c_F}{T} \left(\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial L}\right)_F \\ 
   dL  = \dfrac{m c_L}{T} \left(\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial F}\right)_L 
\end{array}
$$
Take the ratio of the two equations on the right noting that $S$ is constant:
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial L}\right)_S 
   = 
   -\frac{c_F}{c_L}
   \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_L     
   \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial L}\right)_F
$$
Use the triple product rule:
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_L
   \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial L}\right)_F
   \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial F}\right)_T = - 1
   \Rightarrow
   \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_L
   \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial L}\right)_F
   =
   - \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial L}\right)_T 
$$
Finally combine the last two results:
$$
\boxed{
   \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial L}\right)_S 
   = 
   \frac{c_F}{c_L}
   \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial L}\right)_T . 
   }
$$
PS: From the short fragment of the page you posted it looks like your author's writing is not very pedagogical.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped.